# How to Setup an Object before testing

Tags: unit-testing, codeception

I'm setting up some unit tests in Codeception and need to create an instance of an Object. I can do this in _before but this then creates a new instance before every test. I have tried to use _beforeSuite but the constructor for the Object requires an environment variable, from my understanding this won't work as beforeSuite is ran before bootstrap? When I try this out I seem to be getting null instead of the variable.

I am new to testing so I am curious if it is okay to create the Object in _before or if I should be using something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should strive for in testing in general is, that when executing your system-under-test (SUT) this happens in a clearly defined context.  During test execution you want all the aspects that could influence the execution of your SUT under control.  Re-using objects between tests is therefore (normally) not advisable, because a previous test might have made modifications to the objects.  Which may then have an impact on the results of the later tests.  The advice against sharing objects between tests holds even if you know the exact order in which tests will be executed (tests should be independent - lots of information about this on the web, e.g. [Why in unit testing tests should not depend on the order of execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34104801/why-in-unit-testing-tests-should-not-depend-on-the-order-of-execution)).

Therefore, unless in exceptional circumstances, prefer that you have a fresh object for every single test.  You can have it created in `_before`, but it might even be better (for readability purposes) to create it directly within each test case that needs it.