# I want to run three @Test methods in sequential order

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng

I want to run method in the following order A() ->(b)->(c) and i want to run multiple times keeping the order same like A() ->(b)->(c)->A() ->(b)->(c)->A() ->(b)->(c). The code which i mentioned is running as (A)->(A)-(A)-(B)-(B)-(B)-(C)-(C)-(C)

I have tried using invocation count , using priority and data provider at method level but none is working.

```
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Factory;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Test2 {

    int increment;

    @Factory(dataProvider="data")
    public Test2(int increment)
    {
        this.increment=increment;
    }

    @Test()
    public void A()
    {
        String s = "Hi";   
        System.out.print(s+" "+increment);
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods ={"A"})
    public void B()
    {
        String s = "MY Name is"; 
        System.out.print(s+" "+increment);
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods ={"B"})
    public void C()
    {

        System.out.println("Anubhav"+" "+increment);
    }

    @DataProvider(name="data")
    public static Object[][] h()
    {
        Object s[][] ={{1},{2},{3}};
        return s;

    }

}
Expected - A() ->(b)->(c)->A() ->(b)->(c)->A() ->(b)->(c)
Actual - A)->(A)-(A)-(B)-(B)-(B)-(C)-(C)-(C)
```

Comment: I think that it's a very bad idea to do so and most of the plugin and tools don't support test ordering. If your test consist of having 3 sequential tests, simply call the 3 test methods in a single test case.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34104801/why-in-unit-testing-tests-should-not-depend-on-the-order-of-execution

Answer (score 0):

Expecting the execution of test to be in a certain order is usually a smell of a bad test. You usually want independent tests that do not influence each other.

That being said: See [this article](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/preserve-order-in-testng) for test ordering. And [this article](https://www.guru99.com/parameterization-using-xml-and-dataproviders-selenium.html)  for parameterized tests.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. When Data Provider returns multiple data sets then each test or @Test will execute those data sets. see https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders

You have to change your implementation..may be all in same test.